# how to capture the updated budget if they select subway or train and input it into the currency exchange?

Tags: python

```
if transport == "Subway" or transport == "Train":
    
print("That will cost you $3.75, taking that into account we will subtract that from your budget.")
    
print("Your new budget is $" + str(float(budget) - 3.75))

print()

print("We have additionally added a currency exchange converter for certain currencies.")
print()
currency_exchange_USD_EUR = ("Your budget is EUR " + str(float(budget) * .96))
```

Comment: Fix indentation, please.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools available on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Hey! your question is unclear, can you elaborate bit more ? what is that you want to do @redfox178

Comment: "How to capture the updated budget"- Your question is not clear. Your question should include a [mcve] with your input and a description of what is your expected output, and how is it different from your current output? Are you trying to write the output back to the `budget` variable instead of just printing it? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

in your current code you don't update the budget, you just calculate and print it

```
if transport == "Subway" or transport == "Train":
    
    print("That will cost you $3.75, taking that into account we will subtract that from your budget.")
    budget = budget - 3.75 #updating the value of 'budget' here 
    print("Your new budget is $" + str(budget ))

    print()

print("We have additionally added a currency exchange converter for certain currencies.")
print()
currency_exchange_USD_EUR = ("Your budget is EUR " + str(float(budget) * .96))
```

hipe i could help, if you didn't understand anything feel free to ask me in the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You must update the value of the `budget` variable, otherwise it still contains the old value:

```py
if transport == "Subway" or transport == "Train":

    print("That will cost you $3.75, taking that into account we will subtract that from your budget.")

    budget = float(budget) - 3.75 # Added this line
    print("Your new budget is $" + str(budget))

    print()

    print("We have additionally added a currency exchange converter for certain currencies.")
    print()
    currency_exchange_USD_EUR = "Your budget is EUR " + str(float(budget) * 0.96)
```